# differential equation of the form $\frac{du}{dt} = u(t) + f(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

is there any way to analytically solve a differential equation of the form $\frac{du(t)}{dt} = Ku(t) + f(t)$ where k is just a constant?

Answer (score 2):

The given equation $$ \frac{du(t)}{dt} = Ku(t) + f(t)$$

is a first order linear differential equation.

$$ \frac{du(t)}{dt} - Ku(t) = f(t)$$

The integrating factor is $$ e^{-Kt}$$

Thus we get, $$ \frac{du(t)}{dt} e^{-Kt}   - Ku(t)e^{-Kt}   =  e^{-Kt} f(t)$$

Integrating both sides you get $$ e^{-Kt} u(t) =  \int e^{-Kt} f(t) dt + C$$

Solve for $u(t)$ and you are done.

Comment: +1, but $k$ should be $K$.

Comment: @HansLundmark, Yes of course, thanks for your  the attention and comment.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to solve $\dot{u}=K u$, yielding $u=u_0 exp(K t)$.
Then you can replace $u_0$ by a function $g(t)$. You can then inject your new $u(t)$ in your differential equation, and you get a differential equation for $g(t)$. The rest, you can figure out yourself :)